# Failed opening install.inc' when upgrading Drupal 7.x core with Drush 7.x

Tags: 7, drush

I have Drush 7.x installed and when I run 'drush up', on a Drupal 7.x codebase, I get the following error:

```
Drush command terminated abnormally due to an unrecoverable error.
[error]Error: require_once(): Failed opening required '/home/user/public_html/core/includes/install.inc'
```

It seems like Drush 7.x may be looking for Drupal 8.x file structure. How should I be running this command?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I managed to get it fixed after tracking the issue in drush 7, this is caused as you said by trying to load install.inc as Drupal 8 folder structure while you have Drupla 7 structure

I simply modified DRUSH_ROOT/commands/core/core.drush.inc line 1120

```
require_once DRUPAL_ROOT . '/core/includes/install.inc';
```

to be like

```
require_once DRUPAL_ROOT . '/includes/install.inc';
```

I hope this help you.

Comment: OK, great. This seems like it may be a bug, so I filed an [issue](https://github.com/drush-ops/drush/issues/1025) on the Drush GitHub repository.